# Montar varios array atravês de um array bidimensional?

Tags: javascript, array, lógica

Estou precisando da ajuda de vocês, recentemente estou enfrentando um problema que me impede de terminar o meu projeto. Tenho este `array` que representa os serviços de cada funcionário.

```
let servicos = [
[{
    servico_1: 1
}, {
    servico_2: 0
}, {
    servico_3: 0
}],
[{
    servico_1: 0
}, {
    servico_2: 1
}, {
    servico_3: 0
}]
]
```

Preciso criar a relação de serviços, em três novos array ter a seguinte estrutura.

Array numero 1 ficará assim:

```
servico1Arr = [1, 0]
```

Array numero 2 ficará assim:

```
servico2Arr = [0, 1]
```

Array numero 3 ficará assim:

```
servico3Arr = [0, 0]
```

Meu código simplificado:

```
// itera sobre serviços 
for (let i = 0; i < .......) {
            
     let dadoFuncionario = .....
            
     // percorre cada cada valor, servico1,servico2 e servico3
     dadoFuncionario.forEach((servico, i) => {                       
          console.log(i, servico);   
          // resultado: 1 0 0 0 1 0
    });
}
```

Saída do meu `console.log`:

```
1 0 0 0 1 0
```

Comment: estranho esse `array` em javascript isso não funciona

Comment: Não seria assim: `let servicos = [ [ {servico_1 :1}, {servico_2 : 0}, {servico_3 : 0} ], [   {servico_1 :0}, {servico_2 : 1}, {servico_3 : 0}]`?

Comment: este é somente um exemplo, a saída do meu código está bem parecido. porém não deixa de ser um array bidimensional.

Comment: você tem que colocar o real para gente ter certeza

Comment: Vou atualizar minha pergunta. E você consegue me ajudar no problema?

Comment: você veio me criticou por pouca coisa e não me ajudou no meu problema, qual a explicação disto?
O meu problema estava claro, você entendeu bem, não teve necessidade disto!

Comment: Rafael calma rapaz nasceu de 7 meses! muito nervoso

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não é nada muito trivial esse tipo de operação e consequentemente um resposta muito obvia sobre o assunto, mas, temos que sempre criar um código mais dinâmico possível para que funcione para diversas possibilidades com o exemplo dado acima.

Nesse exemplo de `array` foi elaborado um código com duas funções uma para verificar se o elemento já é contido no `array` produto se não cria um novo elemento, se sim acrescenta os valor no item do `array`.

Exemplo:

```js
let servicos = [
  [{servico_1: 1,},{servico_2: 0,},{servico_3: 0,},],
  [{servico_1: 0,},{servico_2: 1,},{servico_3: 0,},],
];

// array produto
let dictionary = [];

// busca de elemento já existente
function getIndex(dic, name) {
  let index = -1;
  for (let i = 0; i < dic.length; i++) {
    if (Object.keys(dic[i])[0] === name[0]) {
      index = i;
      break;
    }
  }
  return index;
}

// construção do array produto
servicos.forEach(function (item) {
  item.forEach(function (i) {
    let index = getIndex(dictionary, Object.keys(i));
    if (index > -1) {
      dictionary[index][Object.keys(i)].push(i[Object.keys(i)]);
    } else {
      dictionary.push({ [Object.keys(i)]: [i[Object.keys(i)]] });
    }
  });
});

console.log(dictionary);
```

Talvez existam outros soluções, essa é um pouco custosa porque ele vai varrer sempre o `array` produto, dependendo da solução talvez tenha que procurar uma nossa solução ou então um forma melhor de montar isso, se for para pequenos casos funciona bem.